# Segmentation Fault with K&R C example 1.9

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am new to C and have hit a problem with an example form K&R C ( section 1.9) not working properly. Here is the code I have copied from the example, and gone over once looking for discrepancies:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int mygetline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

// print longest input line

main() {
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while ((len = mygetline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0) // there was a line
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

// getline: read a line into s, return length
int mygetline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

// copy: copy 'from' onto 'to'; assume to is big enough
void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != "\0")
        ++i;
}
```

When I compile I get the following:

```
cc -Wall -g test.c -o test
test.c:9:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
test.c: In function ‘copy’:
test.c:45:30: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
test.c:45:30: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
```

When I run the program, this happens:

j

```
on@jon-G31M-ES2L:~/c$ ./test
Hello, does this work?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am using gcc as my compiler.

Comment: You may want to get a book written this century..

Comment: K&R is old, but it's a classic, and still well worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the below line:

```
while ((to[i] = from[i]) != "\0")
```

It should be

```
while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
```

Now, as to why the first one was wrong. "\0" is actually a string literal which is stored in some memory (let's say the address is 0x7d5678 just for example), whereas the left side of != is an integer. The compiler automatically knows that such a comparison is wrong and can never pass, so it gives you the warning

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

Also, when you have a string literal in your code, you have no control as to, at what address will it be stored, so the compiler again knows that any comparison with a string literal is wrong hence flags the warning

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

Also, as an additional note, always remember that strings in C can be compared & manipulated only using the strcmp or strncmp group of string functions. You can never do an "=" comparison on a string.
Hope this helps in understanding.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me some great extra info.

Answer (score 7):

Change `"\0"` to `'\0'` in the copy function. "\0" is a string, you want a character.

Comment: Also note that the compiler emitted a warning for this mistake - take-home message: always read and act upon compiler warnings !

Comment: Thanks.  I come from Python where single and double quotes are mostly interchangeable.

Comment: Also to Paul R: I read the compiler message but it didn't help because I didn't understand the difference between single and double quotes and why it shouldn't be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your `copy` function has a typo, `"\0"` instead of `'\0'` (as alluded to by the compiler warnings). the condition is unlikely to occur